# How to set customBackoff parameters in Bean

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka

I have following data for retry strategy:

```
@RetryableTopic(topicSuffixingStrategy = TopicSuffixingStrategy.SUFFIX_WITH_INDEX_VALUE,
            backoff = @Backoff(delay=1000, multiplier=2, maxDelay=16000),
            attempts = 5,
            kafkaTemplate = "templateKafka")
@KafkaListener (...)
```

As I have a lot of topics and the strategy is the same for each one I'm trying to configure as follows:

```
@Bean
public RetryTopicConfiguration myRetryTopic(KafkaTemplate<String, Object> template) {
    return RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder
            .newInstance()
            .setTopicSuffixingStrategy(TopicSuffixingStrategy.SUFFIX_WITH_INDEX_VALUE)
            .customBackoff(...)
            .maxAttempts(5)
            .includeTopics("my-topic", "my-other-topic")
            .kafkaTemplate("templateKafka")
            .create(template);
}
```

I have no idea how to set delay, multiplier and maxDelay in .customBackoff field. I have found no info unfortunately.

Pls give me the hints.

Update:

I did as advised:

```
@Configuration
public class RetryTopicConfig {
@Bean
    public RetryTopicConfiguration myRetryTopic(KafkaTemplate<String, Object> template) {

        final var policy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
        policy.setInitialInterval(1000);
        policy.setMaxInterval(16000);
        policy.setMultiplier(2);

        return RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder
                .newInstance()
                .setTopicSuffixingStrategy(TopicSuffixingStrategy.SUFFIX_WITH_INDEX_VALUE)
                .customBackoff(policy)
                .maxAttempts(5)
                .includeTopics(List.of("topic1","topic2")
                .create(template);
    }
}
```

But when I start app I expect there are 5 retry-topics (retry-0, retry-1, retry-2, retry-3, retry-4) and 1 dlt as I determined 5 attempts. But there are only 2 retry topics (retry-0, retry-1) and 1 dlt, i.e. by default.

```
        @RetryableTopic(kafkaTemplate = "templateKafka")
@KafkaListener(...)
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UniformBackoff` or `ExponentialBackoff` classes to set the delay, multiplier, and maxDelay values in the `customBackoff` field. Here is an example:

```
@Bean
public RetryTopicConfiguration myRetryTopic(KafkaTemplate<String, Object> template) {
    final var policy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
    return RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder
            .newInstance()
            .setTopicSuffixingStrategy(TopicSuffixingStrategy.SUFFIX_WITH_INDEX_VALUE)
            .customBackoff(policy)
            .maxAttempts(5)
            .includeTopics(List.of("my-topic", "my-other-topic"))
            .create(template);
    }
```

Don't forget to fill the variables in ExponentialBackOffPolicy

Comment: Thanks @rafu. But I still have a problem - pls see update above